# R: Getting indices of elements in a sorted vector

Tags: r, performance, algorithm, sorting

I have a sorted vector, let's say

```
v <- c(1, 1, 2, 3, 5, 8, 13, 21, 34)
```

Now I want to find the index `i` of the first element which is bigger than for example `a <- 15`.

I could do something like `i <- which(v > a)[1]`.

But I want to exploit the fact that `v` is sorted, which I don't think `which` cares about.

I could write it myself and divide the interval recursively in halves and search in those partial intervals...

Is there any built-in solution? As usual the main issue is speed and my own function would be slower surely.

Thank you.

Comment: Your solution takes less than 90 microseconds on my machine for a vector of 1e4 elements. Are you sure that this is not fast enough?

Comment: Hmm. You're right. `which(runif(10e6,0,100)>99.99)[1]` takes practically no time also. In my case I have a large vector of datetimes. On my machine it takes 0.015s with one million datetimes. Curiously it makes no difference if sorted or not. `which` indeed is pretty good.

Comment: If you want an improvement, you could implement your suggested algorithm with Rcpp.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

For speed-glutton

```
a <- 10
v <- sort(runif(1e7,0,1000));
Rcpp::cppFunction('int min_index(NumericVector v, double a) {
                  NumericVector::iterator low=std::lower_bound (v.begin(), v.end(), a);
                  return (low - v.begin());
                  }')
microbenchmark::microbenchmark(which(v > a)[1], min_index(v, a), unit="relative")

#Unit: relative
#            expr      min       lq     mean   median      uq      max neval
#which(v > a)[1] 61299.15 67211.58 14346.42 8797.526 8683.39 11163.27   100
#min_index(v, a)     1.00     1.00     1.00    1.000    1.00     1.00   100
```

Answer (score 2):

There is `uniroot`. It is using bisection and is faster on much longer vectors.

```
v <- c(1,1,2,3,5,8,13,21,34)
a <- 15

root <- uniroot(f = function(x) v[x] - a, interval = c(1, length(v)))
my_index <- floor(root$root)
```

Comment: Nice idea, but also not an improvement when benchmarked with `set.seed(42); v <- sort(sample(1:100, 1e4, TRUE))`.

Comment: @Roland Agree. But it is faster with longer vectors. (> 20000)

Answer (score 0):

Just wonder if the following may be useful.

```
Filter(function(x) x > 15, v)[1]
#[1] 21
Find(function(x) x > 15, v, right = FALSE, nomatch = NULL)
#[1] 21
Position(function(x) x > 15, v, right = FALSE, nomatch = NA_integer_)
#[1] 8
```

Comment: This is slower than OP's solution.

Answer (score 0):

`which` isn't exactly slow, so what about `min(which())`:

```
v <- c(1,1,2,3,5,8,13,21,34) 
system.time(
  print(min(which(v > 5)))
)
# [1] 6
# user  system elapsed 
  0       0       0
```

Comment: This is slower than OP's solution.

Comment: Thanks for benchmarking, it's useful to know. I wasn't suggesting my solution was faster or slower, simply that `which()` isn't exactly slow so is it definitely not fast enough for the OP (as, indeed, you've asked)?