# Speeding up a strangely slow Rcpp function

Tags: r, rcpp

I want to rewrite an expensive R function using Rcpp. As I am new to this topic I experimented with some very simple stuff. 
I wrote the following function:

```
Rcpp::cppFunction('
  std::vector<int> test_C(double a) {
    std::vector<int> indices;
    indices.reserve(2);
    indices.push_back(a);
    indices.push_back(a);
    return (indices);
  }
')
```

Now that works all well regarding the result. But it takes 0.1 seconds (which for this task of course is way too much).  Previously I had

```
Rcpp::cppFunction('
  NumericVector test_C(double a) {
    NumericVector indices(2);
    indices[0] = a;
    indices[1] = a;
    return (indices);
  }
')
```

which was equally slow. I am doubting that this is my systems fault. I tried the Rcpp code in the answer of [R: Getting indices of elements in a sorted vector](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30026836/r-getting-indices-of-elements-in-a-sorted-vector) which calculates which[v > a][1] for a numeric vector v (of length 10e7 in my test) and a double a and it worked very very fast.

Any hint what I am doing wrong?

Comment: Please include the R portion of your code as well.  Are you looping and applying this function to each element of your loop?  The second function runs in 1 micro second on my system, which is close to the trivial evaluation time for an Rcpp function.

Comment: I'm curious about why you are filling an integer vector with `double`s.

Comment: nrussell: oh right that makes no sense. I changed it and speed did not increase. Anyway, the version with NumericVector was slow also.

Comment: BrodieG: There is no R portion. What I am doing is: Put the above code in an empty document in RStudio, mark it and execute. After some 5 seconds it is compiled. And then: `a <- Sys.time(); test_C(5); b <- Sys.time(); print (b-a)`.

Comment: use `microbenchmark`.  `Sys.time` is not useful for timing short evaluations.  Also, the way to time that way is `system.time(expression.to.time)`

Comment: `Sys.time` has a max precision of .1 seconds in Windows, which is most likely the reason you got a "slow" timing. You should use a proper benchmarking tool, like those suggested by @BrodieG and @Dirk Eddelbuettel

Comment: I excuted the function 10 times in a row. My (i know not optimal) Sys.time() based measurement gives me 0.203012 secs. The measurement is not the problem. The result just doesn't come immediately.

Comment: Yes, your measurement is the problem. Don't use `Sys.time()`, use the rbenchmark or the microbenchmark packages.

Comment: You're right. Executing 100 times lasts 0.203012 secs also (with Sys.time() which I'll stop using now). Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Are you by chance measuring the compilation too?

```
R> library(rbenchmark)
R> benchmark(test_C(2))[1:4]
       test replications elapsed relative
1 test_C(2)          100   0.001        1
R>
```